# vue with eslint data host let me ask you something about

Tags: image, vue.js, eslint

i'm using Vue3 + eslint + prettier
but i don't understand, eslint error

my vue project images data url host is

image: 'https://picsum.photos/210/118/?image=1',

[image]

but image: "https://picsum.photos/210/118/?image=1"

This input only interpreted it as a sentence.
What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

ESlint wants you to use double quotes here `"` rather than simple quotes `'` because you have both ESlint and Prettier running in pair.

You could either auto-fix it with ESlint or edit the [settings of Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quotes) to prefer simple quotes. I do recommend keeping the default.